# How can we know if image already exists in the album?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, phassetcollection

I have created an album programmatically. I want to check if image already exists in album before adding new image.
you can check with below code
CustomAlbum.shared.saveImage(image: UIImage())
save image like this.

```
import Foundation
import Photos
class CustomAlbum {
    static let albumName = "xyz"
    static let shared = CustomAlbum()
    var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!
    init() {
        func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection! {
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomAlbum.albumName)
            let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
            if let _: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
                return collection.firstObject!
            }
            return nil
        }
        if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
            self.assetCollection = assetCollection
            return
        }
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: CustomAlbum.albumName)
        }) { _, _ in
            self.assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
        }
    }

    func saveImage(image: UIImage) {
        if assetCollection == nil { return }
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let assetPlaceholder = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image).placeholderForCreatedAsset
            let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
            let assetEnumeration: NSArray = [assetPlaceholder!]
            albumChangeRequest?.addAssets(assetEnumeration)
        }, completionHandler: nil)
    }
    func allPhotos(albumName: String = "xyz", albumImages: @escaping ([UIImage]) -> Void) {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var images: [Image] = []
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

        let resultCollections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(
            with: .album,
            subtype: .albumRegular,
            options: fetchOptions)

        resultCollections.enumerateObjects({
            (object, index, stop) -> Void in
            let collection = object
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: nil)
            result.enumerateObjects({
                (object, index, stop) -> Void in
                group.enter()
                images.append(object.getfullImage())
                group.leave()
            })
        })
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            albumImages(images)
        }
    }
}
```

with this code i'm fetching all images of album and comparing against the image I want to save.

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().allPhotos { (images) in 
    let image = UIImage()

}
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36469279/check-if-image-exists-in-photos

Comment: How do you want to check if it exists, based on the name?

Comment: can we compare based on UIImage() object? OR Can we get exact image we save in album? we can get image from PHAsset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare two UIImage objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342897/how-to-compare-two-uiimage-objects)

Comment: No, I'm getting different image while fetching from Album.
It's not same image I saved.

Answer (score -1):

```
 class func getPhotofolder() -> String{
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("hsafetyPhoto") //hsafetyPhoto is my folder name to store the image  and if doesnt exist then system will create one 
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
        try! fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: paths, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    }else{
        print("Already dictionary created.")
    }

    return  paths
}


//Save Image At hsafetyPhoto Document Directory
class func saveImageDocumentDirectory(photo : UIImage, photoUrl : String) -> Bool{

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    let paths =  Utility.getPhotofolder().stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent: photoUrl)
    print("image's path \(paths)")
    if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)

        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }

    }else{
        print(paths)
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.5)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: paths){
            return false
        }else{
            return true
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not talking about saving image in document directory. If I delete the app, all images I saved in document directory will be deleted. What I have done is save image directly in photos under album I've created.